# typeerror while converting Pyobject to java array

Tags: android-studio, chaquopy

The pythor script returns 2d 'float64' numpy array. When I try to assign it to 'double' array in java I am getting this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: TypeError: Cannot convert float64 object to double[]"

---

**EDIT**

```
import librosa as lb 
import numpy as np 
from os.path import dirname, join                                      

def build_feat(fpath):
     filename = join(dirname(__file__), fpath)
     wav,  rate = lb.load(filename, sr=4000)
     X_sample = lb.feature.mfcc(wav, sr=rate, n_fft=512,  win_length=400, n_mfcc=20,
                                hop_length = 256, n_mels = 128, fmin = 100, fmax = 1800)
     X = X_sample.T
     return X
```

Java code:

```
PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("featureExtraction");         
PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("build_feat","107_2b4_Pl_mc_AKGC417L_0.wav");
double[][] feat = obj.toJava(double[][].class);
```

for the same code I am getting a different error now: `com.chaquo.python.PyException: ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous`

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to convert a 1D Numpy array to a 2D Java array. Please edit your question to include the relevant sections of your Python and Java code.

Comment: Also, which version of Chaquopy are you using?

Comment: I am using Chaquopy version 8.0.1.

Comment: `import librosa as lb
import numpy as np
from os.path import dirname, join
                                    
def build_feat(fpath):
    filename = join(dirname(__file__), fpath)
    wav,  rate = lb.load(filename, sr=4000)
    X_sample = lb.feature.mfcc(wav, sr=rate, n_fft=512,  win_length=400, n_mfcc=20, 
    hop_length = 256, n_mels = 128, fmin = 100, fmax = 1800)
    X = X_sample.T
    return X`

Comment: Java code:                                                                                                                                           `if(!Python.isStarted())
        Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("featureExtraction");
        PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("build_feat","107_2b4_Pl_mc_AKGC417L_0.wav");
        double[][] feat = obj.toJava(double[][].class);`

Comment: for the same code I am getting a different error now:                                                                             `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Audiodata/112_1p1_Ll_sc_Litt3200_0.wav flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.cmpe.healthcareai/com.cmpe.healthcareai.RespiratoryActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous`

Comment: Please don't post blocks of code in comments, they lose their formatting and become difficult to read. Instead, click the "edit" link above and add them to your question, as I've just done.

Comment: I'll have a look at your code and get back to you later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the array being transposed and therefore non-contiguous.

**This issue is fixed in Chaquopy 9.0.0.** With older versions, you can work around it by either returning the original array (`X_sample`), or making a copy after transposing (`X_sample.T.copy()`).

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I tried hard to format code in comment  section, didn't think about editing the question. Sorry about that